# 4 different functions to pass pointers to each other, but for some reason my program never runs to the end, and I am not quite sure why

Tags: c

I'm currently working on a program to convert feet/inches to meters/cm. For this I need to use 3 different functions in my assignment, none of which call each other. Those 3 functions are listed below.

```
void readLengthUS()  {
    int *feet;
    double *inches;
    int x;
    double y;
    printf("Enter feet and inches (seperated by a space):\n");
    scanf("%d %lf", &x, &y);
    *feet = x;
    *inches = y;
}
void convert_length_to_metric(int *feet, double *inches)  {
    int *meters;
    double *centimeters;
    *meters = *feet * 0.3048;
    *centimeters = *inches * 2.54;
}
void output_length_to_metric(int *feet, double *inches, int *meters, double *centimeters)  {
    printf("%d feet and %lf inches converted to %d meters and %lf centimeters.\n", *feet, *inches, *meters, *centimeters);
}
```

The lengthToUS function below is used to call the above functions.  Every single time I run my program, it exits after receiving the user input, and I am not quite sure why its happening. Could anyone help me with this?

```
void lengthToUS(int *x)  {
    int *feet;
    double *inches;
    int *meters;
    double *centimeters;
    readLengthUS();
    convert_length_to_metric(&feet, &inches);
    output_length_to_metric(&feet, &inches, &meters, &centimeters);
```

Comment: `readLengthUS` isn't taking parameters or returning anything, so all its variables are local and disappear when the function terminates. `main` has a bunch of uninitialized values that cause undefined behavior when you try to dereference them. Pass them as parameters to `readLengthUS`.

Comment: I tried changing it to "void readLengthUS(int *feet, double *inches)", and calling it through: "readLengthUS(&feet, &inches);", but that didnt change anything in regards to the error either. How would I go about fixing it?

Comment: That won't work either because `&` takes the reference of a pointer. You already have `int *`, so you can pass it in without the `&`. Keep working at it--I think it's more instructive than giving you the answer. Make sure to compile with `-Wall -Werror` flags. BTW, your ints in main could just be non-pointers.

Comment: oh I see, thought that I always had to use ```&``` when passing on pointers. Thank you, that actually helps a lot.

Comment: If you have `int ...` then pass it with `&` to take its address and turn it into a pointer. If you have `int *...` then no need for `&`.

Answer (score 1):

You are segfaulting because pointers are *uninitialized*

Also, you have a number of errors/warnings about statements with no effect

There are too many things that need fixing to enumerate them manually

*Always* compile with `-Wall -O2 -Werror`.

If you had, you'd be able to fix the warnings/errors.

*However*, one of the major reasons you're having so much trouble is that you're passing down [or *should* be passing down] *four* pointers.

A *much* better way is to create a `struct` that has all the values in it, so you only have to pass around a pointer to the [common] `struct`.

I've added a refactored version at the bottom [that compiles cleanly] and, although untested, probably fixes most of the errors

---

To get you started, here is the compiler diagnostic output. It was generated with: `gcc -c -Wall -Werror -O2 orig.c`

```
orig.c: In function ‘readLengthUS’:
orig.c:14:10: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
  *inches - y;
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
orig.c: In function ‘lengthToUS’:
orig.c:43:27: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘convert_length_to_metric’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  convert_length_to_metric(&feet, &inches);
                           ^~~~~
orig.c:18:31: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
 convert_length_to_metric(int *feet, double *inches)
                          ~~~~~^~~~
orig.c:43:34: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘convert_length_to_metric’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  convert_length_to_metric(&feet, &inches);
                                  ^~~~~~~
orig.c:18:45: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double **’
 convert_length_to_metric(int *feet, double *inches)
                                     ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
orig.c:44:26: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘output_length_to_metric’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  output_length_to_metric(&feet, &inches, &meters, &centimeters);
                          ^~~~~
orig.c:28:30: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
 output_length_to_metric(int *feet, double *inches, int *meters, double *centimeters)
                         ~~~~~^~~~
orig.c:44:33: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘output_length_to_metric’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  output_length_to_metric(&feet, &inches, &meters, &centimeters);
                                 ^~~~~~~
orig.c:28:44: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double **’
 output_length_to_metric(int *feet, double *inches, int *meters, double *centimeters)
                                    ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
orig.c:44:42: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘output_length_to_metric’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  output_length_to_metric(&feet, &inches, &meters, &centimeters);
                                          ^~~~~~~
orig.c:28:57: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
 output_length_to_metric(int *feet, double *inches, int *meters, double *centimeters)
                                                    ~~~~~^~~~~~
orig.c:44:51: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘output_length_to_metric’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  output_length_to_metric(&feet, &inches, &meters, &centimeters);
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
orig.c:28:73: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double **’
 output_length_to_metric(int *feet, double *inches, int *meters, double *centimeters)
                                                                 ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
orig.c: In function ‘readLengthUS’:
orig.c:13:8: warning: ‘feet’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  *feet = x;
  ~~~~~~^~~
orig.c:14:2: warning: ‘inches’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  *inches - y;
  ^~~~~~~
orig.c: In function ‘convert_length_to_metric’:
orig.c:23:10: warning: ‘meters’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  *meters = *feet * 0.3048;
  ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
orig.c:24:15: warning: ‘centimeters’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  *centimeters = *inches * 2.54;
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
orig.c: In function ‘lengthToUS’:
orig.c:30:2: warning: ‘centimeters’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  printf("%d feet and %lf inches converted to %d meters and %lf centimeters.\n",
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   *feet, *inches, *meters, *centimeters);
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
orig.c:40:10: note: ‘centimeters’ was declared here
  double *centimeters;
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
orig.c:30:2: warning: ‘meters’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  printf("%d feet and %lf inches converted to %d meters and %lf centimeters.\n",
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   *feet, *inches, *meters, *centimeters);
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
orig.c:39:7: note: ‘meters’ was declared here
  int *meters;
       ^~~~~~
orig.c:30:2: warning: ‘inches’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  printf("%d feet and %lf inches converted to %d meters and %lf centimeters.\n",
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   *feet, *inches, *meters, *centimeters);
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
orig.c:38:10: note: ‘inches’ was declared here
  double *inches;
          ^~~~~~
orig.c:30:2: warning: ‘feet’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  printf("%d feet and %lf inches converted to %d meters and %lf centimeters.\n",
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   *feet, *inches, *meters, *centimeters);
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
orig.c:37:7: note: ‘feet’ was declared here
  int *feet;
       ^~~~
```

---

I reindented your code, so here's the exact file that produced the above errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
readLengthUS(void)
{
    int *feet;
    double *inches;
    int x;
    double y;

    printf("Enter feet and inches (seperated by a space):\n");
    scanf("%d %lf", &x, &y);
    *feet = x;
    *inches - y;
}

void
convert_length_to_metric(int *feet, double *inches)
{
    int *meters;
    double *centimeters;

    *meters = *feet * 0.3048;
    *centimeters = *inches * 2.54;
}

void
output_length_to_metric(int *feet, double *inches, int *meters, double *centimeters)
{
    printf("%d feet and %lf inches converted to %d meters and %lf centimeters.\n",
        *feet, *inches, *meters, *centimeters);
}

void
lengthToUS(int *x)
{
    int *feet;
    double *inches;
    int *meters;
    double *centimeters;

    readLengthUS();
    convert_length_to_metric(&feet, &inches);
    output_length_to_metric(&feet, &inches, &meters, &centimeters);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's a [heavily] refactored version that fixes most problems [compiles cleanly, but is *untested*].

You *may* still have some math [formula] errors and problems with integer truncation.

Notably, I think the conversion to metric calculations are wrong. You're setting `meters` from *just* `feet`. And, setting `centimeters` from *just* `inches`.

I've included a another version further below that has [what I think is] the corrected formula.

Anyway, here's the code. It should get you further:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct dist {
    int feet;
    double inches;
    int meters;
    double centimeters;
};

void
readLengthUS(struct dist *dist)
{

    printf("Enter feet and inches (seperated by a space):\n");
    scanf("%d %lf", &dist->feet, &dist->inches);
}

void
convert_length_to_metric(struct dist *dist)
{

    dist->meters = dist->feet * 0.3048;
    dist->centimeters = dist->inches * 2.54;
}

void
output_length_to_metric(struct dist *dist)
{

    printf("%d feet and %lf inches converted to %d meters and %lf centimeters.\n",
        dist->feet, dist->inches, dist->meters, dist->centimeters);
}

void
lengthToUS(int *x)
{
    struct dist dist;

    readLengthUS(&dist);
    convert_length_to_metric(&dist);
    output_length_to_metric(&dist);
}
```

---

Here's another version with my corrections for your metric calculation formula.

It's a little difficult to divine your *intent* because of the *types* you used for `meters` and `centimeters` (i.e. `meters` is `int` and `centimeters` is `double`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct dist {
    int feet;
    double inches;
    int meters;
    double centimeters;
};

void
readLengthUS(struct dist *dist)
{

    printf("Enter feet and inches (seperated by a space):\n");
    scanf("%d %lf", &dist->feet, &dist->inches);
}

void
convert_length_to_metric(struct dist *dist)
{
    static double inches_in_meter = 39.370079;
    double inches = (dist->feet * 12.0) + dist->inches;
    double meters;

    // get fractional meters
    meters = inches;
    meters /= inches_in_meter;

    dist->meters = meters;
    meters -= (int) dist->meters;
    dist->centimeters = meters * 100;
}

void
output_length_to_metric(struct dist *dist)
{

    printf("%d feet and %lf inches converted to %d meters and %lf centimeters.\n",
        dist->feet, dist->inches, dist->meters, dist->centimeters);
}

void
lengthToUS(int *x)
{
    struct dist dist;

    readLengthUS(&dist);
    convert_length_to_metric(&dist);
    output_length_to_metric(&dist);
}
```

Comment: Hey, never used -Wall -02 -Werror before. How can I use that? currently using gcc